# possible of using nearby connections api advertising in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I'm trying to implement a chat which use google nearby connections API,
I saw in the API page builder [AdvertisingOptions.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AdvertisingOptions.Builder) is has an option called setLowPower(boolean lowPower), but it isn't implemented in the code,
is it recommend/ possible to be in  advertising mode while on background please?
thanks in advance,

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156322/nearby-connections-and-foreground-background-services for details on using Nearby Connections in the background. The low power flag is still planned to be properly exposed, but it's slow going because it hasn't been a high priority.

Comment: Do be careful with advertising continuously in the background. If you're not rotating  the endpoint info at a semi-random interval, it's possible to track the device. That's one reason we haven't exposed a true background mode using something like a PendingIntent.